# My tab links turned into /user/%/edit, node/%/edit, etc

Tags: 7, routes

Links on tabs turned into `/user/%/edit`, `/user/%/contact`, `node/%/edit`, `admin/structure/types/%/fields`, etc.
Also, the links on Administration Menu module have the same issue.

Here's what I did so far.

1. I've cleared all cache via Admin Menu -> Flush all cache, via Development -> Performance and via emptying MySQL cache_* tables. Didn't solve.
2. I noticed that tabs are themed by the `menu_local_tasks()` function. I traced the function to `includes/menu.inc`, where I found the following snippet, which makes me think it might be related to this function.

```
* For example, the ancestors of node/12345/edit are:
 * - node/12345/edit
 * - node/12345/%
 * - node/%/edit
 * - node/%/%
 * - node/12345
 * - node/%
 * - node
```

UPDATE:
Where is `'%'`, of the above URLs, being populated? I want to be able to trace it.

Comment: and what happens when you click on node/%/edit ? These are menu router items which i believe you already know.

Comment: It shows that the page could not be found. I have no clue what menu router items are.

Comment: Where does '%' get populated?

Comment: menu router is an entry to register a particular path. node module registers node/%/edit, node/%/revisions, node/%, etc paths so it can use arguments in place of "%" sign. By default, when you see a menu, you should not see the "%" sign. Instead, these paths should be actual paths with value replaced.

Comment: You should read about wildcard in menu system. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7 . So in case of node/%/edit the % can be replaced by an integer and that integer can be passed as argument to the page callback or access callback. You can also have wildcard autoloaders like node/%node/edit now in this case %node will pass that value to node_load function. Read the hook_menu function for more information. Also refer to http://drupal.org/node/102338 for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys! I accidentally commented out a line in menu.inc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 775 of `/include/menu.inc` was commented out.

Comment: good that you found the solution. Hence it is said [__NEVER HACK DRUPAL CORE__](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core) ;-) I think that may be the reason that you also got a downvote for the question.

Comment: nope, I never hack core. It must of been those rare accidents

Comment: ...now that I'm thinking, I should of phrase the q'n to ask what was causing the issue, not why it happened. Oh well, better answer some questions to make up for the negative reputation!

Comment: well you could try if that helps, and yes you're always welcome to share your knowledge here :-) Drupal community always appreciates it :-)